# How to prove that a set is equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

My goal is to prove that the set: AB = $\{ ab \mid a \in A, b \in B \} = \mathbb{Q}$ where $A=\{ a \in \mathbb{Q} \mid a < 1 \}$ and $B=\{ b \in \mathbb{Q} \mid b<2 \}$.
I understand that $AB=\mathbb{Q} \iff (AB \subseteq \mathbb{Q}) \land (\mathbb{Q} \subseteq AB)$ but I'm unsure how to prove $(AB \subseteq \mathbb{Q}) \land (\mathbb{Q} \subseteq AB)$ with rigour.

Comment: Informally : $1 \in B$; thus $A \subseteq AB$. Now assume that for some $q \ge 1 \in \mathbb Q$ we have that $q \notin AB$. But $q = (-q)(-1)$ and $-q < 0 < 1 \in A$ and $-1 < 2 \in B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

1. One of the two claims in $(AB\subseteq\mathbb Q)\land (\mathbb Q\subseteq AB)$ is very easy to show.
2. To show the other, use the fact that for every $q\in \mathbb Q$, you have $q=(-1)\cdot(-q)$ and $q=1\cdot q$. The first equation will be useful for positive values of $q$, the second for negative ones.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $AB\subseteq \mathbb Q$, since the product of rationals is rational.

For any $r\in\mathbb Q$, if $r>0$, we can write $r=(-1)\cdot (-r)$ so $r\in AB$; if $r\leq0$ then $r=r\cdot 1\in AB$. Hence $\mathbb Q\subseteq AB$.

Combining above results we have $\mathbb Q=AB$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $q \in \mathbb Q$. if $q=0$ write $q$ as $(0)(0)$. If $q >0$ write it as $(-1)(-q)$ and if $q <0$ write it as $ (q) (1)$. In each case we have written $q$ as $ab$ with $a <1$ and $b <2$. Hence $\mathbb Q \subset AB$. The other inclusion follow from the fact that product of two rational numbers is a rational number.